# Running an .exe file in cygwin.

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I'm absolutely new in CYGWIN and Bash in total, so, I guess that there is an answer somewhere in a documentation, but I'm not succeeded finding it.

I have two files coexisting in a directory: *file* and *file.exe*. If I call **file** (using CYGWIN terminal), it gives me an error "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" (because it accesses the *file*), but if I call **file.exe**, it works well. I've found in the [manual](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-exe) that "the shell script has precedence and is selected for execution of *file*", but it seemes that it is wrong in my situation. So, what should I do to excecute *file.exe* calling **file** in terminal? Thanks in advance.

p.s. **./file** also doesn't work; **./file.exe** works well

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin follows the Linux rules, where there are no default extensions for
executable files. Such files are defined as executable by modifying their
attributes using the `chmod` command, not by their extension.

You should not call the files by the same name, as "file" does not invoke
"file.exe".

Comment: Thank  you for your answer! Yes, I tried to change its attribute by `chmod +x file.exe` but nothing has changed. =(

Comment: The problem is the presence of `file`. Setting the attributes of "file.exe" won't help. Cygwin will not launch "file.exe" unless you execute "file.exe". It will execute "file"  if you type "file".

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `file` to something else. 
This should be enough

```
mv file file2
```

The `.exe` so called magic handler inside cygwin will then treat `file.exe` and `file` as synonym.
Please also note that `file` is also a command of a base package

```
$ which file
/usr/bin/file
$ cygcheck -f $(which file)
file-5.32-1
```

and it is not a good idea to have a duplicate program name